# does there exist a set of k positive integers such that each subset has a sum that is an nth power for some $n\ge 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, contest-math

> Prove or disprove that there exists a set of k positive integers such that each subset has a sum that is an nth power for some $n\ge 2$.

If $S = \{a_1,\cdots, a_k\}$ denotes the set, then there are potentially $\dfrac{k(k+1)}2$ possible subsets. I'm not sure how to ensure that each subset has a sum that's an nth power, though I think trying small values of k and using induction might help. $k=1$ is trivial. But for $k=2$ it seems a lot harder (especially to come up with small examples). One example I came up with was $\{3^6 4^7, 3^6 2^{15}\}.$

Comment: if $n>2$, Fermat would appear to be a problem, no?  If $a,b$ are both in your set then we'd need $a=A^n, b=B^n$ and $a+b=C^n$.

Comment: There are $2^k$ possible subsets. There are $k(k+1)/2$ subsets of size $1$ or $2.$

Comment: @lulu I believe $n$ can vary with the subset. Essentially, the sums are all perfect powers. But agree, that is not clear. That's always a risk when putting a quantifier at the end of a sentence - it is unclear where the $\exists n$ goes.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  Agreed.

Comment: The case $k=2$ is also trivial: if $(a,b,c)$ is a Pythagorean triple then $S =\{a^2,b^2\}$ works.